# How to receive a file and save it with socat

Tags: linux, port, socket, socat

**** This is for learning purpose. I just like to deep dive into sockets, tcp, packets, etc.

For doing tests and learning, I began to "play" with socat

CONTEXT (tests) :

1- Bind a port to a shell script

```
socat -u tcp-l:7777,fork system:/path/to/test.sh
```

2- test from an other terminal

```
echo "message 1" | netcat 192.168.0.x 7777
```

THIS simple test works, the .sh gets triggered

QUESTION :
to learn further, how would I receive a file and save it ?

Comment: with netcat just use nc -parametershere > file.ending

Answer (score 3):

```
socat -u TCP-L:7777,fork OPEN:/tmp/test.out,creat,append
```

Answer (score 0):

If the shell script `/path/to/test.sh` contains something like

```
cat >/path/to/target.dat
```

(i.e. read from stdin, write to a file) then you can "transfer" a file by means of

```
cat /path/to/source.dat | netcat 192.168.0.x 7777
```